# Align chapter and section headings after their number/counter

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chapters

How do I align headings whithout interfering with my TOC?
This what I have:

```
1 Chapter
1.1 Section
1.1.1. Subsection
```

This is what I need

```
1      Chapter
1.1    Section
1.1.1. Subsection
```

I am using the `titlesec` package, but so far I have not been able to find a solution. Another problem, basically preventing me from "cheating", is that I am using the `tocloft` package. Thus, I need to find a way to align my headings without interfering with the TOC.

MME:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{12.5}{0}\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{14pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{14pt}{7pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{14pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{14pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\bhead}{0pt}{14pt}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\secnumwidth}
\setlength{\secnumwidth}{0pt}
\providecommand*{\usesecnumwidth}{0pt}

\newcommand*{\secnumwidthbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\secnumwidth
      \global\secnumwidth=\wd0\relax
    \fi
  \endgroup
  \leavevmode
  \hbox to 
    \ifdim\usesecnumwidth>\secnumwidth
      \usesecnumwidth
    \else
      \secnumwidth
    \fi
  {#1\hfil}%
}

\let\org@chapterformat\chapterformat
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \secnumwidthbox{\org@chapterformat}%
}

\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{%
  \secnumwidthbox{#3\autodot\hfill\enskip}%
}

\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \string\gdef\string\usesecnumwidth{\the\secnumwidth}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim\usesecnumwidth=\secnumwidth
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Rerun LaTeX, because \noexpand\usesecnumwidth
      has changed}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Where do you want to align the headings? In the TOC or at the place where the section headers appear (and the chapter etc. headers...)?

Comment: I need to align the headings where the section and chapter headers appear. Basically "inline" alignment. All headings within the TOC are aligned. Now I need to do the same thing where all headings appear.

Comment: @DanielKeys: So really "inline", i.e. as a bead on a string just in a line of "text"? If it would be like this, pardon me, it would look awful in my point of view.

Comment: Can you add the `\titleformat` code you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example uses class `scrreprt` as example (the question has not specified the class). The methods can be adopted to other classes (more or less easily).

Macros `\chapterformat` for the number in `\chapter` and `\othersectionlevelsformat` for the number in `\section` and friedns are redefined. First the number including dot and separation space is measured, then the number is set in a box with a width that can hold the longest entry. The width of the widest number is written into the `.aux` file at the end of the document. Therefore two LaTeX runs are necessary.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\secnumwidth}
\setlength{\secnumwidth}{0pt}
\providecommand*{\usesecnumwidth}{0pt}

\newcommand*{\secnumwidthbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\secnumwidth
      \global\secnumwidth=\wd0\relax
    \fi
  \endgroup
  \leavevmode
  \hbox to 
    \ifdim\usesecnumwidth>\secnumwidth
      \usesecnumwidth
    \else
      \secnumwidth
    \fi
  {#1\hfil}%
}

\let\org@chapterformat\chapterformat
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \secnumwidthbox{\org@chapterformat}%
}

\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{%
  \secnumwidthbox{#3\autodot\hfill\enskip}%
}

\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \string\gdef\string\usesecnumwidth{\the\secnumwidth}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim\usesecnumwidth=\secnumwidth
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Rerun LaTeX, because \noexpand\usesecnumwidth
      has changed}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Package `titlesec`

Package `titlesec` redefines internals of KOMA-Script. A place for hooking into `titlesec` to add `\secnumwidthbox` would be `\ttlh@hang`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{12.5}{0}\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{0}\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{14pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{14pt}{7pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{14pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{14pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\bhead}{0pt}{14pt}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\secnumwidth}
\setlength{\secnumwidth}{0pt}
\providecommand*{\usesecnumwidth}{0pt}

\newcommand*{\secnumwidthbox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\secnumwidth
      \global\secnumwidth=\wd0\relax
    \fi
  \endgroup
  \leavevmode
  \hbox to 
    \ifdim\usesecnumwidth>\secnumwidth
      \usesecnumwidth
    \else
      \secnumwidth
    \fi
  {#1\hfil}%
}

\let\org@chapterformat\chapterformat
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \secnumwidthbox{\org@chapterformat}%
}

\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{%
  \secnumwidthbox{#3\autodot\hfill\enskip}%
}

% Patch for titlesec
\patchcmd\ttlh@hang{%
  \sbox\z@{#2\strut\ttl@calc\hspace{#3}}%
}{%
  \sbox\z@{\secnumwidthbox{#2\strut\ttl@calc\hspace{#3}}}%
}{}{\errmessage{Cannot patch \string\ttlh@hang}}

\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \string\gdef\string\usesecnumwidth{\the\secnumwidth}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim\usesecnumwidth=\secnumwidth
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Rerun LaTeX, because \noexpand\usesecnumwidth
      has changed}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result titlesec]

Comment: Your example works just fine, but I can´t use it with my titleformat etc. I can´t figure out why. I posted a MME in my previous posting. I guess there is a conflict between my spacing and its measuring. By the way: I am using a custom document class. I changed the the renewcommand into a newcommand and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to wrap the heading counters in a fixed-width box. For example, a 40pt width box:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\makebox[40pt][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother
```

[image: sample preview]

[image: wraper box]